# 301 Redirects problem - urls with ? and =

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I'm new with 301 redirects through .htacces.

I can get simple redirects as

```
redirect 301 /test.html http://www.domain.com/test2.html
```

to work but I have some urls like this

```
redirect 301 /test.asp?Group=100 http://www.domain.com/test3.html
```

and for some reason these don't work.

Thanks.

Comment: Just remove query string and it will be copied unchanged to new URL (e.g. `redirect 301 /test.asp http://www.domain.com/test3.html`). If you need to ONLY redirect on specific query string (e.g. redirect when `Group=100` but ignore if any other value) .. then you have to use mod_rewrite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is set of rules for URLs you have provided:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} =group=113 [NC]
RewriteRule ^group\.asp$ http://domain.dk/til-born.htm? [NC,R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} =product=1136 [NC]
RewriteRule ^product\.asp$ http://www.domain.dk/til-born/bukser.html? [NC,R=301,L]
```

1. As you can see query string is matched separately to the page name. So .. for each of such redirects you need 2 lines: RewriteCond & RewriteRule.
2. The rule above will do EXACT match, which means `/group.asp?group=113&param=value` will not be redirected because query string is `group=113&param=value` which is more than just `group=113`.

   To have such redirect working (when there are some optional parameters in query string) you have to modify it: `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)group=113(&|$) [NC]` -- this will match `group=133` anywhere in query string (`group=113` and `group=11366` are still different, so no problems here).
3. This needs to be placed in .htaccess in website root folder. If placed elsewhere some tweaking may be required.

Answer (score 0):

The `Redirect` directive (as far as I know) matches only on the path, not querystring.  Instead, use `RewriteRule`.  The `QSA` instructs the rewrite engine to append the querystring onto the new redirected URL.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^test\.asp http://www.domain.com/test3.html [L,R=301,QSA]
```

Comment: Hey Michael and LazyOne 

Thanks for the answer, it was what I was affraid of. 

I have around 50 different querystrings that need to be 301 redirected to a new url. 

LazyOne - You write I have to use mod_rewrite - I will try googeling a little about that. 

Thanks

Comment: @Martin Use @ before username otherwise person will not be notified about your comment. If you want -- I can provide you with such rewrite rule, but you have to check if mod_rewrite is enabled on your server (in most cases it is).

Comment: @LazyOne Okay thanks for the @ advice, I did not know, I'm new at writing here on stackoverflow, usually I can find the answer in some other thread in here - Its a goldmine. 

It could be great if you could provide me with such. Just to clarify I have 2 different query strings like:

group.asp?group=113 
and
/product.asp?product=1107

Mod rewrite should be enabled. 

Thanks, I really appreciate the help.

Comment: @Martin Update your question with details -- the more info you provide the better. Please provide from URL => to URL.

Comment: @LazyOne 

redirect 301 /group.asp?group=113 http://www.domain.dk/til-born.html
redirect 301 /product.asp?product=1136 http://www.domain.dk/til-born/bukser.html
etc.

I hope this is enough, only thing changing is the ID number